# Combining D3 Visualization

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am trying to combine two D3 Visualizations. I found a question before, but it did not really have a solution.

When I combine the two files the visualizations overlap and produce this:

[image]

the streamgraph component:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    body {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    .chart {
        background: #fff;
    }
    p {
        font: 12px helvetica;
    }
    .axis path, .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 2px;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    button {
        position: absolute;
        right: 50px;
        top: 10px;
    }
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>


<div class="chart">
</div>

<script>
    chart("Data.csv", "blue");
    var datearray = [];
    var colorrange = [];
    function chart(csvpath, color) {
        if (color == "blue") {
            colorrange = ["#045A8D", "#2B8CBE", "#74A9CF", "#A6BDDB", "#D0D1E6", "#F1EEF6"];
        }
        else if (color == "pink") {
            colorrange = ["#980043", "#DD1C77", "#DF65B0", "#C994C7", "#D4B9DA", "#F1EEF6"];
        }
        else if (color == "orange") {
            colorrange = ["#B30000", "#E34A33", "#FC8D59", "#FDBB84", "#FDD49E", "#FEF0D9"];
        }
        strokecolor = colorrange[0];
        var format = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%y");
        var margin = {top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 50};
        var width = document.body.clientWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
        var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        var tooltip = d3.select("body")
                .append("div")
                .attr("class", "remove")
                .style("position", "absolute")
                .style("z-index", "20")
                .style("visibility", "hidden")
                .style("top", "30px")
                .style("left", "75px");
        var x = d3.time.scale()
                .range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scale.linear()
                .range([height-10, 0]);
        var z = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .range(colorrange);
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .orient("bottom")
                .scale(x)
                .ticks(d3.time.years, 10); //tick on every 10 years
        /*.scale(x)
         .orient("bottom")
         .text(date)
         //;*/
        //. tickFormat(x)
        //. tickValues(date)
        //was already there but out of view -> changed the left margin
        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y);
        var stack = d3.layout.stack()
                .offset("silhouette")
                .values(function(d) { return d.values; })
                .x(function(d) { return d.date; })
                .y(function(d) { return d.value; });
        var nest = d3.nest()
                .key(function(d) { return d.key; });
        var area = d3.svg.area()
                .interpolate("cardinal")
                .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
                .y0(function(d) { return y(d.y0); })
                .y1(function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); });
        var svg = d3.select(".chart").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        /* correct this function
         var graph = d3.csv(csvpath, function(data) {
         data.forEach(function(d) {
         d.date = format.parse(d.date);
         d.value = +d.value;
         });*/
        var graph = d3.csv(csvpath, function(raw) {
            var data = [];
            raw.forEach(function (d) {
                data.push({
                    key: d.Country,
                    date : new Date(1980,0,1), //I had a bug in creating the right dates
                    value : parseInt(d['1980-1989'].replace(',','')) //get rid of the thousand separator
                });
                data.push({
                    key: d.Country,
                    date : new Date(1990,0,1),
                    value : parseInt(d['1990-1999'].replace(',',''))
                });
                data.push({
                    key: d.Country,
                    date : new Date(2000,0,1),
                    value : parseInt(d['2000-2009'].replace(',','') )
                });
            });
            var layers = stack(nest.entries(data));
            x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]);
            svg.selectAll(".layer")
                    .data(layers)
                    .enter().append("path")
                    .attr("class", "layer")
                    .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d.values); })
                    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); });
            //adding .text causes axis to dissapear
            svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "x axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                //.text(date)
                    .call(xAxis);
            svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "y axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ", 0)")
                //.text(value)
                    .call(yAxis.orient("right"));
            svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "y axis")
                    .call(yAxis.orient("left"));
            var pro;
            svg.selectAll(".layer")
                    .attr("opacity", 1)
                    .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
                        svg.selectAll(".layer").transition()
                                .duration(250)
                                .attr("opacity", function(d, j) {
                                    return j != i ? 0.6 : 1;
                                })})
                    .on("mousemove", function(d, i) {
                        var mousex = d3.mouse(this);
                        mousex = mousex[0];
                        var invertedx = x.invert(mousex);
                        //find the largest smaller element
                        var dd = d.values.filter(function(d) { return d.date <= invertedx; });
                        dd = dd[dd.length -1]; //use the last element
                        pro = dd.value;
                        d3.select(this)
                                .classed("hover", true)
                                .attr("stroke", strokecolor)
                                .attr("stroke-width", "0.5px");
                        tooltip.html( "<p>" + d.key + "<br>" + pro + "</p>" ).style("visibility", "visible");
                    })
                    .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
                        svg.selectAll(".layer")
                                .transition()
                                .duration(250)
                                .attr("opacity", "1");
                        d3.select(this)
                                .classed("hover", false)
                                .attr("stroke-width", "0px");
                        tooltip.html( "<p>" + d.key + "<br>" + pro + "</p>" ).style("visibility", "hidden");
                    })
            var vertical = d3.select(".chart")
                    .append("div")
                    .attr("class", "remove")
                    .style("position", "absolute")
                    .style("z-index", "19")
                    .style("width", "1px")
                    .style("height", "380px")
                    .style("top", "10px")
                    .style("bottom", "30px")
                    .style("left", "0px")
                    .style("background", "#fff");
            d3.select(".chart")
                    .on("mousemove", function(){
                        var mousex = d3.mouse(this);
                        mousex = mousex[0] + 5;
                        vertical.style("left", mousex + "px" )})
                    .on("mouseover", function(){
                        var mousex = d3.mouse(this);
                        mousex = mousex[0] + 5;
                        vertical.style("left", mousex + "px")});
        });
    }
</script>
```

Map component:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>U.S Immigration Data Visualization</title>
<style>
.country:hover{
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.text{
  font-size:10px;
  text-transform:capitalize;
}
#container {
    margin: 10px 10%;
    border:2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: #e1eafe;
}
.hidden { 
  display: none; 
}
div.tooltip {
  color: #222; 
  background: #fff; 
  padding: .5em; 
  text-shadow: #f5f5f5 0 1px 0;
  border-radius: 2px; 
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #a6a6a6; 
  opacity: 0.9; 
  position: absolute;
}
.graticule {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #bbb;
  stroke-width: .5px;
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}
.equator {
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

</style>
</head>
<br>

  <h1><center>U.S Immigration Data Visualization</center></h1>
  <h2><b>Work in Progress</b></h2>
  <h3><b>Ex-USSR countries included in Russia</b></h3>
  <h3><b>Ex-Yugoslavia included in Macedonia</b></h3>


  <div id="container"></div>

<script src="js/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.geo.tile.v0.min.js"></script>
<script>
d3.select(window).on("resize", throttle);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 9])
    .on("zoom", move);


var width = document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth;
var height = width / 2;

var topo,projection,path,svg,g;

var graticule = d3.geo.graticule();

var tooltip = d3.select("#container").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip hidden");

setup(width,height);

function setup(width,height){
  projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .translate([(width/2), (height/2)])
    .scale( width / 2 / Math.PI);

  path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

  svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .call(zoom)
      .on("click", click)
      .append("g");

  g = svg.append("g");

}

d3.json("data/world-topo-min.json", function(error, world) {

  var countries = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features;

  topo = countries;
  draw(topo);

});

function draw(topo) {

  svg.append("path")
     .datum(graticule)
     .attr("class", "graticule")
     .attr("d", path);


  g.append("path")
   .datum({type: "LineString", coordinates: [[-180, 0], [-90, 0], [0, 0], [90, 0], [180, 0]]})
   .attr("class", "equator")
   .attr("d", path);


  var country = g.selectAll(".country").data(topo);

  country.enter().insert("path")
      .attr("class", "country")
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("id", function(d,i) { return d.id; })
      .attr("title", function(d,i) { return d.properties.name; })
      .style("fill", function(d, i) { return d.properties.color; });

  //offsets for tooltips
  var offsetL = document.getElementById('container').offsetLeft+20;
  var offsetT = document.getElementById('container').offsetTop+10;

  //tooltips
  country
    .on("mousemove", function(d,i) {

      var mouse = d3.mouse(svg.node()).map( function(d) { return parseInt(d); } );

      tooltip.classed("hidden", false)
             .attr("style", "left:"+(mouse[0]+offsetL)+"px;top:"+(mouse[1]+offsetT)+"px")
             .html(d.properties.name);

      })
      .on("mouseout",  function(d,i) {
        tooltip.classed("hidden", true);
      }); 


  //EXAMPLE: adding some capitals from external CSV file
  d3.csv("Data.csv", function(err, capitals) {

   capitals.forEach(function(i){
     addpoint(i.CapitalLongitude, i.CapitalLatitude );
    });

  });

}


function redraw() {
  width = document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth;
  height = width / 2;
  d3.select('svg').remove();
  setup(width,height);
  draw(topo);
}


function move() {

  var t = d3.event.translate;
  var s = d3.event.scale; 
  zscale = s;
  var h = height/4;


  t[0] = Math.min(
    (width/height)  * (s - 1), 
    Math.max( width * (1 - s), t[0] )
  );

  t[1] = Math.min(
    h * (s - 1) + h * s, 
    Math.max(height  * (1 - s) - h * s, t[1])
  );

  zoom.translate(t);
  g.attr("transform", "translate(" + t + ")scale(" + s + ")");

  //adjust the country hover stroke width based on zoom level
  d3.selectAll(".country").style("stroke-width", 1.5 / s);

}



var throttleTimer;
function throttle() {
  window.clearTimeout(throttleTimer);
    throttleTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
      redraw();
    }, 200);
}


//geo translation on mouse click in map
function click() {
  var latlon = projection.invert(d3.mouse(this));
  console.log(latlon);
}


//function to add points and text to the map (used in plotting capitals)
function addpoint(lat,lon,text) {

  var gpoint = g.append("g").attr("class", "gpoint");
  var x = projection([lat,lon])[0];
  var y = projection([lat,lon])[1];

  gpoint.append("svg:circle")
        .attr("cx", x)
        .attr("cy", y)
        .attr("class","point")
        .attr("r", 1);

  //conditional in case a point has no associated text
  //if(text.length>0){

  //  gpoint.append("text")
 //         .attr("x", x+2)
 //         .attr("y", y+2)
 //         .attr("class","text")
  //        .text(text);
  //}

}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What should the output be?

Comment: Both the map and graph should displayed and operate on the same page

Comment: where is the overlap ?

Comment: It's shown by the picture I posted with the question. The map and streamgraph should both be displayed separately, but on the same html page.

Comment: all i see is a blue box with text above it, :/

Comment: Yes because that is the error I am having. I want the streamgraph to be displayed separtely from the map, but both be on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer without the code you actually use when you 'combine' the two SVG elements, and without the data or a working example.

What I've done is take the 2 basic components, the streamgraph (and `svg` node inside `<div class="chart">`) and the map (a separate `svg` node in `<div id="container"></div>`), and create working code that combines the 2:

http://plnkr.co/edit/WjlObRIasLYXOuEL4HDE?p=preview

This is the basic code:

```
<body>
    <div class="chart">
    </div>
    <div id="container">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var width = 300;
    var height = width / 2;

    // Equivalent of streamgraph code...
    var svg_stream = d3.select(".chart")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .append("rect")
      ... // rect attributes

    // Equivalent of map code...  
    var svg_map = d3.select("#container")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .append("circle")
      ... // circle attributes
    </script>
</body>
```

What's *inside* each `svg` shouldn't make a difference to the positioning, so I've just used a `rect` to represent the streamgraph and a `circle` for the map. I've taken as much of the CSS and code from your snippets as it makes sense to. If you combine the two components as in the example above, you should not see any overlap. I'm not really able to correct your version as I don't know how you did it.

Note - You should also avoid defining duplicate variable names (like `var svg` for both SVGs) when combining the components